# Running an OpenGLES app on mac iphone emulator fails

Tags: android, ios, iphone, visual-c++, opengl-es

I set up the vcremote correctly(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147405.aspx#ConfigureVS) and it connected. I tried to run the default visual studio OpenGLES app on the iphone emulator through vcremote and it built the app just fine, but just as the emulator opened it crashed with the following error: 
"Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-target-select remote localhost:3031". Command 'target-select'. Fn 'Target select' failed"

I have no idea how to fix this, and it seems that there are not a lot of people running into this problem. Any help would be much appreciated, even if it just helps me understand the error message better, SOMETHING!

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with this problem for hours and hours until I found the following link:
[Remote Debugger Port Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments)

> The Visual Studio Remote Debugger can run as an application or as a
> background service. When it runs as an application, it uses a port
> that is assigned by default as follows:
>  Visual Studio 2022:
> 4026
>  Visual Studio 2019:
> 4024
>  Visual Studio 2017:
> 4022
>  Visual Studio 2015: 4020
>  Visual Studio 2013: 4018
> Visual Studio 2012: 4016

The port 3031 seems to be coming from out of the blue!

I am using Visual Studio 2017 so I used the following command to start up vcremote:
`vcremote --secure false --nativeDebugProxyPort 4022`
After that the iPhone simulator and App started up, but the debugging started to work only after restarting the App during the debug session (which I did by rebooting the iPhone simulator).

I still did not get the pairing working on a secure connection yet :-( Any hints are welcome!